# Confused by value returned by main()

Tags: c++, macos

I have compiled and executed this code on macOS in Xcode 10.0 (clang: Apple LLVM version 10.0.0) and it's returning `255`. On the other hand, on Windows in Visual Studio Community Edition v.15.8.6 it's returning `-1`. Can someone explain this behaviour on macOS? Code listed below.

```
int main() {
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems (like macOS or Linux) the return-code from a process is made up of several parts, and the return-code from `main` is only stored in the low eight bits of the `int` value.

Most modern systems uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to represent negative integers, and with that the signed value `-1` becomes `255` because all bits in the byte will be set.

Because of this it's not recommended that you return negative numbers from `main` (or call [`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) with a negative number). Instead use only small non-negative numbers, where `0` is considered success. Or of course use the standard `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` macros.

---

Windows, not being a POSIX systems, doesn't really care about this, and uses the whole `int` value for the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Certain OSs (POSIX) have return code range limit from `0` to `255` (effectively a `uint8_t`).  `-1` converted to `uint8_t` is 255.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the OS the error code returned to the parent process is a char, int8_t, uint8_t or possibly anything else. From the numbers you get MacOS seems to have uint8_t so a -1 shows up as 255 while Windows has an int8_t or larger so -1 is reported.

This has nothing to do with your program but with the datatype used in the OS to report return codes of processes. Nothing you can change there.

Note: You should not use -1/255 as exit code as that is already used to signal an error loading your program on unix/linux system. It's best to stick with 1,2,3,... as error codes to avoid conflicts.